# Linear programming to find a graph circuit

Tags: graph, linear-programming

The question itself is pretty simple... This is a vechicle routing problem.
I have a directed graph
[image]

I need to get a linear programming model that will somehow tell me the shortest circuit that visits all nodes, and starts and ends at the star. You are allowed to go over an edge more than once. A node is any crossing on the image.
We had like 4 hours of this in class, I have no idea where to even start...
I'm not expection anyone to give me the full model, but I was hoping someone would tell a strategy so I could do this.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: I doubt LP (or shortest path) is intended here. This is more like a TSP problem. Smaller instances can be solved with MIP models. Allowing to revisit nodes/edges can be handled by preprocessing the distance matrix.

Answer (score 0):

I would start from Dijkstra's algorithm for undirected graphs. There are some variants with similar or better performance. Take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem#Undirected_graphs, pick a choice, and keep us informed ... :)

Answer (score 0):

The answer here seems to be very easy.  (That is, very easy in theory, very hard and a lot of work to code in practice).

This seems like a straight-forward TSP (Travelling Salesperson Problem).  Read about some general literature on TSP.  You need to set up and solve a TSP where your nodes are the "cities" in a TSP.  You also need to include your star as a city in the TSP.

The Dijkstra algorithm will *not* give you a solution.  The Dijkstra algorithm is used for finding fastest/shortest paths between a node and other nodes in a (typically road-) network.  However, distance-wise your problem is super-simple:  Getting the cheapest travel cost (and path) from one node to another node in your problem is (almost) trivial.

If you are to solve this problem "for real" (not just discuss it), you need to acquire a TSP solver that is able to take your network (both edges and nodes) as input.  Your input needs to specify which edges are directed and which are uni-directed.  A lot of work in practice:  Even if you use a tool, you still need to familiarize yourself with the tool.